# Windows Service not working on Development server

Tags: c#, windows-services, jpegtran

I have a windows service, which basically do the optimization of the image, once a day, below are the steps it performs for the optimization:

1. Copies original files to backup folder.

2. Now optimizes image and moves it to the Temp Folder.

3. Now overrides the actual files with the optimized version from Temp folder to original folder.

4. Then deletes the Temp Folder.

Below is my approach:

1. Initiates process class and access command prompt .exe file

2. inputs jpeg .exe and it's argument.

This concept works on my local machine with windows service, however when i do the same on server, it does not do anything.
Can anyone guide to the right path on this.

Comment: Can't tell from the information you have provided, but aren't there any logs of the service's activity you can have a look at? If not, it's a good idea to make a logging mechanism for the service.

Comment: Actually it does not throws any error, i tried to write the logs in a text file, it executed 1st line for the backup folder creation and then it stopped while exxecuting jpegtran, but with no errors.

Comment: Have a look at the EventViewer, if you have access.

Comment: No errors in event viewer too, it just has the logs for service start and service stop.